# How can I store asynchronous operations and later assign them to a related instance?

Tags: flutter

I'm building a form using `flutter_form_builder` package. Certain form fields must be geolocated; for this purpose I'm using `geolocator` package.

Geolocation operations return futures. I do not want to block/await for the geolocation operation to complete because it would slow down filling out the form (i.e. can be less responsive due to bad signal, etc.).

I do not want to await any futures until the user hits submit; hopefully, by the time they do, most (if not all) futures will have completed. How can I avoid waiting for the futures to complete until the form is fully filled out?

My current idea is to have an instance in the main form widget state that will store the futures along with the key to the form field that they are associated with. This will allow me to update the form when a future completes.

This untested code demonstrates the above:

```
class GeolocationManager {
  const GeolocationManager({
    required this.form,
  }) : geolocatedFields = const {};

  /// Synchronous form JSON.
  final Map<String, dynamic> form;

  /// Futures associated by key to a geolocation request.
  final Map<String, Future<Position>> geolocatedFields;

  void add(
    String key,
    Future<Position> future,

    /// Parses a json form field and inserts the associated [Position] before
    /// converting back to a json form field.
    dynamic Function(Position, dynamic) toJson,
  ) {
    /// Store the future along with an associated form field key.
    geolocatedFields[key] = future;

    /// When the future completes, update the form json.
    future.then((position) => form[key] = toJson(position, form[key]));
  }
}
```

Comment: What about using a `FutureBuilder` for each field that needs a geolocation? You could display a progress indicator while the futures are in progress. You don't have to await the results, the futures can run in parallel and your user will have feedback that something is going on but won't get blocked.

Comment: @PeterKoltai Some fields include taking photos. These fields open a camera module which allows multiple photos to be taken (each photo must be geolocated individually for accuracy). The `FutureBuilder` approach would work, however, if the user decided to add a new photo to the same field, then they would first have to wait for all previous photos to finish being geolocated; I want to avoid that to ensure the smoothest progression.